# How does an anonymous list work in a python list comprehension?

Tags: python, for-loop

Given the function:

```
def merge(nums1, nums2):
    return [max(nums1, nums2).pop(0) for _ in nums1 + nums2]
```

I think it works like:

```
def merge(nums1, nums2):
    ans = []
    while nums1 or nums2:
        if nums1 > nums2:
            ans += nums1[0],
            nums1 = nums1[1:]
        else:
            ans += nums2[0],
            nums2 = nums2[1:]
    return ans
```

The function takes the maximum of the current leftmost value in nums1 and num2 and appends it to a new array.

Can anyone explain to me why the first one is equivalent to the second one?
Specifically, the part:

```
for _ in nums1 + nums2
```

confuses me most.

Similar ones like to initialize an array of size n:

```
[0 for _ in xrange(n)]
```

My understanding is that

```
for _ in xrange(n)
```

just tells to execute n times, and fill the array with returned value from expression before for similarly,

```
for _ in nums1 + nums2
```

execute len(nums1)+len(nums2) times, but if we pop, **the length should changed.**

So why have I misunderstood? Is it that the part after in clause is a copy of the original?

Comment: You explained the code. There is just a little thing you missed. `num1 + num2` is only evaluate once at the beginning. It results in a new anonymous list which the loop iterates over. Changes to one of the two variables in the loop are not affecting the loop anymore.

Comment: Not only is this code needlessly obfuscated, it doesn't even accomplish its function efficiently. `pop(0)` requires the entire list to be shifted in memory - making this O(n*n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1:

> Can anyone explain to me why the first one is equivalent to the second one?

A1:

We can use this function and observe something:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,0,5]
>>>
>>> print merge(a,b)
[4, 1, 2, 3, 0, 5]
>>> a
[]
>>> b
[]
```

The `max(nums1, nums2).pop(0)` is to compare first elements of the both lists.
Whenever it executes one time of loop, it will pop the first element of the max list. Actually, the `max` returns the object is using memory reference so the both lists will gradually reduce their elements utils finishing the for-loop. Therefore, this is why `a` and `b` variables are empty after the function finishs.

Let me show the function how to work.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,0,5]
>>> merge1(a,b)
Step1
nums1:  [1, 2, 3]
nums2:  [4, 0, 5]
The max list is  [4, 0, 5]
So it will pop : 4
Step2
nums1:  [1, 2, 3]
nums2:  [0, 5]
The max list is  [1, 2, 3]
So it will pop : 1
Step3
nums1:  [2, 3]
nums2:  [0, 5]
The max list is  [2, 3]
So it will pop : 2
Step4
nums1:  [3]
nums2:  [0, 5]
The max list is  [3]
So it will pop : 3
Step5
nums1:  []
nums2:  [0, 5]
The max list is  [0, 5]
So it will pop : 0
Step6
nums1:  []
nums2:  [5]
The max list is  [5]
So it will pop : 5
[4, 1, 2, 3, 0, 5]
```

And I attach my code:

```
def merge1(nums1, nums2):
    list_ = []
    count = 1
    for _ in nums1 + nums2:
        print 'Step%s' % count
        print 'nums1: ' , nums1
        print 'nums2: ' , nums2
        print 'The max list is ', max(nums1, nums2)
        print 'So it will pop :', max(nums1, nums2)[0]
        list_.append(max(nums1, nums2).pop(0))
        count +=1
    return list_
```

According to the workflow, You will see `max(nums1, nums2).pop(0)` is equivalent to `ans += nums1[0];nums1 = nums1[1:];` or `ans += nums2[0];nums2 = nums1[1:];`.

---

Q2:

> for _ in nums1 + nums2
>   execute len(nums1)+len(nums2) times, but if we pop, the length should changed.

A2:

No, After for-loop reads the number or object as executing count, the `pop` can't dynamically effect the executing count.

I can offer the equivalent code for you.

```
def merge1(nums1, nums2):
    return [max(nums1, nums2).pop(0) for _ in range(len(nums1) + len(nums2)]
```

demo:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,0,5]
>>> print merge1(a,b)
[4, 1, 2, 3, 0, 5]
```

So has it happened? Nothing.

---

Q3:

> Specifically, the part: for _ in nums1 + nums2

A3:

According to my A2, you can image it to `for _ in range(len(nums1) + len(nums2)`, they are equivalent. The for-loop just wants the number of the element as executing count.

Answer (score 2):

The key misunderstanding is that this:

```
for _ in nums1 + nums2
```

creates a new list that is iterated over.  The code can be written like so to the exact same effect:

```
def merge(nums1, nums2):
    another_list = nums1 + nums2
    return [max(nums1, nums2).pop(0) for _ in another_list]
```

As you can see, `another_list` never changes, even as `nums1` and `nums2` are slowly eaten.